# Can I burn VirtualBox VM into real environment?

Tags: virtual-machine, virtualbox

I haven't found a lot by googling but was thinking about burning virtual machine image into a real system instead of a virtual one to have exact copy but not inside a VM.

From theory it should be really possible and quite easy as OS would just detect hardware changes. However in practise, I am not sure how to accomplish that.

I would appreciate any help about this topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In some linux based systems is posible (I have done it and work fine in ubuntu for example) but it is most dificult in windows systems because have not very good handling of hardware changes (like motherboard or CPU), you could start by cloning your hdd with some tool like udpcast, cross your fingers and start praying

For Ubuntu you could try some of this:

- Use the [remastersys](http://sourceforge.net/projects/remastersys/) tool.
- Clone the whole virtual hdd with [udpcast](http://www.udpcast.linux.lu/), [clonezilla](http://clonezilla.org/) or some similar tool.
- Follow this [instructions](http://eggsonbread.com/2010/01/28/move-ubuntu-to-another-computer-in-3-simple-steps/).

Comment: I have Ubuntu which needs to be placed outside the VM. Maybe you have some tips? :)